# Gradient Overlay alignment disturbed while exporting artboard to files as JPGs in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, artboard, layer-style

Trying to export artboards as JPGs using Files>>Exports>>Artboard_to_Files. But the gradient overlay alignment is changed when exported. Also, I can't rasterize layer styles as it's applied to the group. Kindly suggest to me the best possible option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible work around

1. Make sure the PSD is saved before you proceed
2. Right click the groups with layer effects, and do *Merge Group*
3. Do the export
4. Close the document without saving

Comment: Doing the Same, this trick works well. Thanks a lot.